# Quiz Generator using NLTK/Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

The goal of this application is produce a system that can generate quizzes automatically. The user should be able to supply any word or phrase they like (e.g. "Sachin Tendulkar"); the system will then look for suitable topics online, identify a range of interesting facts, and rephrase them as quiz questions.

If I have the sentence "Sachin was born in year 1973", how can I rephrase it to "Which Year was sachin born?"

Comment: So you want the system to produce the question with incorrect grammar? :(

Comment: Natural language processing is a very difficult field of research and the problem you are describing is not trivial.  I'm afraid you won't be able to write such a program unless you really dig into this topic.

Comment: See [ELIZA](http://www-ai.ijs.si/eliza/eliza.html)

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, this is a very hard open research question.  However, you might be able to get away with a simple solution a long as your "facts" follow a pretty simple grammar.

You could write a fairly simple solution by creating a set of transformation rules that act on parse trees.  So if you saw a structure that matched the grammar for "X was Y in Z" you could transform it to "Was X Y in Z ?", etc.  Then all you would have to do is parse the fact, transform, and read off the question that is produced.